# Why does declaring similar object name with HashMap has no conflict?

Tags: java, oop, object, hashmap

I have a question. Why does the code below can't be run with eclipse because of variable conflict?

```
PdfPTable testObj1 = new PdfPTable(6);
PdfPTable testObj1 = new PdfPTable(6);
```

but if I use HashMap with loop it will work:

```
Map<String, PdfPTable> hash = new HashMap<>();

    for (i = 1; i <= 1; i++){
        hash.put("testObj" + String.valueOf(i), new PdfPTable(6));
        hash.put("testObj" + String.valueOf(i), new PdfPTable(6));
    }
```

Could somebody explained to me why bottom example can be run? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `testObj1` can't have the same name than `testObj1`

Comment: because you are declaring `testObj1` 2 times in first case and not in second case

Comment: FYI second part in a map are values part and it can be repetitive

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the first case you're creating variables with specific variable names at compile time. So your compiler throws an error if you have 2 variables with the same name in the same scope.

In the second case you're actually using Strings as keys for an HashMap. Using the same key in a HashMap leads to overwriting the old value stored for this key. Even then this has nothing to do with variable names here.

Instead of your second example you could also write

```
Map<String, PdfPTable> hash = new HashMap<>();
hash.put("testObj1", new PdfPTable(6));
hash.put("testObj1", new PdfPTable(6));
```

This should show that you're actually overwriting your first instance of `PdfPTable` with a new second one.

Comment: `Using the same key in a HashMap leads to overwriting the old value stored for this key. ` I didn't know this. Thanks for crystal explanation and example.

Comment: @sg552 You always should have a look at the [Java API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/) to determine the behaviour of library classes and their methods. They're quite good and often also provide examples of dos and don'ts

Answer (score 4):

The two examples are unrelated. In the first one you try to declare two variables with the same name in the same scope, which is not allowed.

In the second example, you try to put two identical keys in a `HashMap`, which will result in only one key being added (since duplicate keys are not allowed), and the second `put` statement will overwrite the original `PdfPTable` value with the second `PdfPTable` value.

Answer (score 2):

It's a syntactic problem, you can't have 2 variables with the same name.
The compiler doesn't allow this and says "Duplicate local variable".

Thake a look at [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html).

Answer (score 1):

This code will create ambiguity in the local variables, if you want to call `testObj1.ToString();` What object would you actually call?

```
PdfPTable testObj1 = new PdfPTable(6);
PdfPTable testObj1 = new PdfPTable(6);
```

The for loop, you create two anonymous objects, there has no variable name, therefor you let the hashmap hold the reference to them, instead of a variable. Logical your two examples does not match, the code could simply be changed to the following and then logically do the same.

```
PdfPTable testObj1 = new PdfPTable(6);
PdfPTable testObj2 = new PdfPTable(6);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, you are creating two variables with same name and assigning values to it. Hence it leads to name conflict at compile time.

In the second case, you are just storing values to hash map with key as string. Here Its nothing to do with variable name. You could also have written this way,

```
String testObj1 = "testObj1";
hash.put(testObj1, new PdfPTable(6));
hash.put(testObj1, new PdfPTable(6));
```

it is obvious it is nothing to do with variable declaration or any naming convention. But if would have declared testObj1 two or more times this way,

```
String testObj1 = "testObj1";
String testObj1 = "testObj1";
```

It would have again led you to naming conflict at compile time.

Storing values in hashmap with same key is allowed and it replaces the value.

for every unstored key , there is always a value assigned and it is null. put() method always returns previous value of the respective key.

suppose  we are storing values to map by this way,

```
Map<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
String previousValue = hashMap.put("key1","value1");
//previousValue would be null.
previousValue = hashMap.put("key1","value2");
//Now previous value would be "value1"
previousValue = hashMap.put("key1","value3");
//Now previous value would be "value2"
```

So, It is obvious that storing values with same key is allowed and it is just overriding previous values to the value we are providing.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler show the error because of duplicate local variable.

In the second, you are just setting the key as "testObj" which is valid.